# Getting CORS error after deploying Spring boot service and UI through Google Compute Shell

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, cors

I am new to **google cloud** and I have deployed a Spring Boot application and **Angular JS** application through **Google Cloud Shell**.
Started Spring Boot app by "java -jar MyAppName.jar &" command and UI server is started with "npm start". **The web preview URL for UI is "https://8080-xx-123456789-default.region-zone.cloudshell.dev"** and for Spring boot service rest end point is "https://**8301**-xx-123456789-default.region-zone.cloudshell.dev/maintenance". When this rest end point is invoked using Angular JS $http.post(), it is failing and browser console displays below error.

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://8301-xx-123456789-default.region-zone.cloudshell.dev/maintenance' from origin 'https://8080-xx-123456789-default.region-zone.cloudshell.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.*

*8301-xx-123456789-default.region-zone.cloudshell.dev/maintenance:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED*

My server.js in npm start command is:

```
var express= require('express');
var app=express();
app.use(express.static('myUIProjectName'));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(process.env.port || 8080,'127.0.0.1');
console.log('UI server is listening on port 8080');
```

My Angular JS controller code.

```
 var loginController = app.controller('auditController', function ($scope, $http, 
$rootScope, 
$location, $window, ServiceProcessor, fileUploadService, PageNavigatorService, 
DataTransferService, DownloadTransferService) {
$scope.uploadFile = function () {
    $scope.expenditureList = [];
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    var uploadUrl = "https://8301-xx-123456789-default.region- 
   zone.cloudshell.dev/maintenance";
    var promise = fileUploadService.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    promise.then(function (response) {
        let calculationResponse = response.calculationResponse;
        $scope.calculationResponse = calculationResponse;
        let expenseNameToExpenseDetails = calculationResponse.expenseNameToExpenseDetails;
        for (const [expenseName, expenditure] of Object.entries(expenseNameToExpenseDetails)) 
{
            $scope.expenditureList.push(expenditure);
        }
        DataTransferService.set(calculationResponse);
    }, function (response1, response2) {
        $scope.serverResponse = 'An error has occurred';
    });
};

app.service('fileUploadService', function ($http, $q) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
    //FormData, object of key/value pair for form fields and values
    var fileFormData = new FormData();
    fileFormData.append('file', file);

    var deffered = $q.defer();
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fileFormData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        // headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'withCredentials': true}

    }).success(function (response) {
        deffered.resolve(response);

    }).error(function (response) {
        deffered.reject(response);
    });

    return deffered.promise;
}
});
```

My Spring boot code is below:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({
    FileStorageProperties.class
    })
 @ComponentScan({packages}) 
public class EasymaintenanceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EasymaintenanceApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("https://8301-xx-123456789- 
   default.region-zone.cloudshell.dev","http://127.0.0.1:5500");
        }
    };
  }

}
```

Controller code:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
//@RequestMapping ("/maintenanceService")
public class MaintenanceController {

@Autowired
private MaintenanceBL maintenanceBL;

@Autowired
private FileStorageService fileStorageService;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MaintenanceController.class);

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@PostMapping("/maintenance")
public UploadFileResponse calculateMaintenance(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
throws Exception {
    UploadFileResponse response = null;
    try {
        String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);
        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();
        CalculationResponse calculationResponse = maintenanceBL.readMaintenanceFile(fileName);
        response = new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
                file.getContentType(), file.getSize(), calculationResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred while calculating maintenance", null, e);
    }
    return response;
  } 
}
```

CORSHandler class (doFilter method is hitting successfully):

```
@Component
public class CORSHandler implements Filter {

public static final String X_CLACKS_OVERHEAD = "X-Clacks-Overhead";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Request is hitting");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User- 
   Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range");
    System.out.println("Request is chained");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using one of the allowed origins in your Controller instead of just "*"

Like in your corsConfigurer Bean you have allowed "https://8301-xx-123456789-default.region-zone.cloudshell.dev" and "http://127.0.0.1:5500"

```
   @Bean
   public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
           @Override
           public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
           registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("https://8301-xx-123456789- 
           default.region-zone.cloudshell.dev","http://127.0.0.1:5500");
        }
      };
    }
```

So in your controller please check by using one of these origins like :

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://127.0.0.1:5500")
    @PostMapping("/maintenance")
    public UploadFileResponse calculateMaintenance(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile 
           file) 
           throws Exception {
           UploadFileResponse response = null;
           try { ...
```

If that works, It will be great,  Regards !

Comment: Thanks @Prashant for replying. I tried the above solution, still getting the same issue. Pleaelet me know if I need to share more information from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this happens when you try to communicate between different servers or the same server but with different port addresses. You need to add a cross-origin configuration on your microservice end. Some time (happened with me) this @crossorigin annotation will override by another configuration, then in that case you need to add a global filter to wite list, all the requested coming to your APIs.

Here, I am sharing a small code snippet to adding a filter to remove cross-origin issue.

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token, X-Csrf-Token, Authorization");

    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

    System.out.println("********* CORS Configuration Completed *********");

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
 }
}
```

Now create a Bean of this class like below

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean =
            new FilterRegistrationBean(new CORSFilter());
    registrationBean.setName("CORS Filter");
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registrationBean.setOrder(1);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

That's it hope your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav for replying. I tried the above solution, still getting the same issue. Please let me know if I need to share more information from my code.

Comment: @AmitSingh please feel free to communicate me on my mail gaurav.mute@gmail.com for further assistance.

Comment: Sure @Gaurav. Thanks.